# What could be the "more" secure app access to (owned) google mail account from C#?

Tags: c#, gmail, smtpclient

**Context**

In the last two years I was using C# code to send emails via my dedicated gmail account. For the code, please see below **code exhibit #1**. I also had to enable less secure app access interactively logging to this gmail account. Recently I noticed that gmail rejects the email what the C# code tries to send., and when interactively logged in, it stated that someone using my password tried to log on, and Google rejected it. (yes, it was my C# program). So it seems Google automatically reset that allow less secure app access...

**Question**

Anyway, I just wondering that instead of setting "allow less secure" what would be the appropriate "secure enough" from C#, I am already using SSL.
(note: *I just want sending emails*)

**Code Exhibit #1**

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtp.gmail.com, 587)
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mygmailaccount@gmail.com", "mypassword")),
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    EnableSsl = true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Activate two factor authentication and then generate application-specific passwords on your gmail account which your application can use to connect to the SMTP server:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

> When you sign up for 2-Step Verification, we normally send you verification codes. However, these codes do not work with some apps and devices, like Outlook. Instead, you’ll need to authorize the app or device the first time you use it to sign in to your Google Account by generating and entering an App password.

The password is then associated with the application using it, so it shouldn't be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Gmail API. User log in using his credentials and you receive access token and refresh token. Now you gain access to user's account by access token, if it expires then you use refresh token to renew access token. Thanks to it you don't store user's credentials in plain text and you have access to well documented API.

[Gmail API Overview](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)

[.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet)

Accessing account this way Google doesn't make any problems.